# How can I verify my Ansible Playbooks are secure and they don't contain errors?

Tags: security, ansible, lint

I want to analyze my Ansible Playbooks and get some feedback and check if they have errors beyond the Ansible plugin for VSC

I already used VSC extension

Answer (score 0):

When I am interacting with Ansible content, I use known mechanisms such as Ansible playbook syntax check, check mode and diff mode, Ansible Lint, and Ansible VS Code Extension.

All those mentioned before can find a lot of errors and security threats, but I've always wanted a solution that finds errors and recommends me improvements for a particular module, collection role, etc., and not just general-purpose rules. So, there's also an additional tool we can use to find hard-to-catch errors and ensure security - Steampunk Spotter (https://steampunk.si/spotter/ ; notice: I am affiliated with it). It provides an Assisted Automation Writing tool that analyzes and offers recommendations for your Ansible content.

As we keep track of all available Ansible content, we detect many things such as changes in parameter names and their default values, module redirections and deprecation warnings, use of FQCN, requirements collection version mismatches, and a lot more.

Besides security and errors, one of our prominent use cases is to facilitate Ansible upgrades, especially from lower Ansible versions. As this can take a lot of time manually, especially if you have a lot of playbooks and tasks, Spotter allows selecting your target Ansible version (e.g., 2.13) and after scanning it will show you hints, warnings, and errors that need to be addressed to do a safe upgrade.

Spotter can be used from CLI, GUI, and some integrations (GitHub, GitLab, VSC is coming soon). For instance, starting with the CLI (see https://gitlab.com/xlab-steampunk/spotter-cli) is quite simple as that:

```bash
pip install steampunk-spotter
spotter scan playbook.yaml
```

Visit FAQ (https://steampunk.si/blog/steampunk-spotter-frequently-asked-questions/) if you have any questions.

Comment: Can I try it for free @anoman? It looks really cool!

Comment: Sure, you can start for free (here: https://steampunk.si/spotter/) by registering for a new Spotter account, which will give you the BASIC subscription plan (and free access to the PRO plan while in Beta).